# Dealing with difference in timezones in local and remote server

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, timezone

Assume my local server (`A`) clock is at `18/2/2015 00:01:00` (GMT +8)

`A` sent an api request which contains parameters `start_time` and `end_time` in unix time. Eg. `1424131200` (17/2/2015 00:00:00) and `1424217599` (17/2/2015 23:59:59) respectively.

Remote server (`B`) stored a timestamp column called `created_at` in unixtime, which means the timezone is interpreted based on the `B`'s timezone clock settings (?)

Now, `B` supposedly reads the timestamp parameter as it is, using the same time zone. But, I notice that `B` queried it wrongly. After googling for solutions, I found that because `B` is using UTC as its timezone. Meaning that the clock in `B` is 8 hours behind `A`.

So, instead of querying `17/2/2015 @ 12am` until `17/2/2015 @ 11.59pm`, it queried `17/2/2015 @ 12am` until `17/2/2015 @ 3.59pm`. Notice the difference between the end time, 11.59pm and 3.59pm? 8 hours difference.

I guess `B`'s clock is always 8 hours behind `A`'s clock at the time of api request, which is at `17/2/2015 16:01:00`. So, the query result always returns wrong information. It will be fine if the api request is executed the same time as the remote server.

I don't how to explain this, but this problem is giving me a headache to synchronize it all. How do I deal with this issue? I can't seem to find any explanation on this. Is using unix timestamp in mysql server a best practice?

Comment: Unix time is *always* UTC.

Comment: Thanks for info. But how do I synchronize it so that it reads as GMT +8 during the api request?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘*reads as GMT +8*’? Unix time is *always* UTC. If you want to show what the time was in GMT+8 for a specified Unix time then you'll have to perform a mathematical operation.

Comment: I just wanna find out if the remote server is using different time zone, because it queried wrong result.

Comment: `select @@time_zone;` and `select @@system_time_zone;` will give you the time zone of the MySQL dbms server and of the underlying host OS. See [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: Thanks Mike. I've checked with the remote server, it uses UTC.